# How add Tap effect to stackpanel?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

Is possible to add a tap effect to a stackpanel or other controls?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "TiltEffect"? A behavior will help you here.

Comment: Sorry, TiltEffect is tap effect on a control(stackpanel, grid...).

Comment: Behavior and Trigger will help you with any effect you want. It is some kind of animation that runs on your control. You just need to define which kind of animation it shall be, some shacking, tilting, ... and attach it